# Resource file modification date

Tags: c#, .net, date, resources

I am getting an image from a resource file like this:

```
Image img = (Image)Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(imgName) as Image;
```

Is there a way to get the **modification date** of this image?

Comment: I *expect* that as a resource you only have the name/contents pair, not full file metadata. I would not *personally* expect this to be possible. I could be wrong, of course.

Comment: ill handle it in other way, because i needed it for my own http server, but ill just generate md5sum from file and send etag to browser, so than ill compare md5sums and i hope that will let me know if browser got same file or not

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, you won't be able to access that information as the image is loaded into the assembly as binary information, not as a file.